# Excel VBA Colon

Tags: vba, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB Using colons to put two statements on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411711/vb-using-colons-to-put-two-statements-on-same-line)

I have the following declaration in Excel VBA

```
Public Const cdbArea = 1: Public Const cdbDist = 2: Public Const cdbChange1 = 4: Public Const cdbChange2 = 5: Public Const cdbTR = 5:
Public Const crbArea = 1: Public Const crbDist = 2: Public Const crbTerr = 3: Public Const crbChange1 = 4: Public Const crbTR = 5:
Public Const cdbWeek1 = 4
```

On first glance, the Colons look like separators, but I have never used this syntax before.

What are the Colons for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put the statements on separate lines, if you like:

```
Public Const cdbArea = 1
Public Const cdbDist = 2
Public Const cdbChange1 = 4
```

Or, you can separate them with colons as in your example above.

Answer (score 3):

Another use of the colon is to set specific variables to a calling statement:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    testWithOptions thirdParameter:="SecondParameterSkipped", firstParameter:="firstParam"
End Sub

Sub testWithOptions(firstParameter As String, Optional secondParameter As String, Optional thirdParameter As String)
    MsgBox "FirstParamter:  " & firstParameter & vbCrLf & _
                "ThirdParamter:  " & thirdParameter
End Sub
```

Notice the third parameter is set before the first and secondParameter (which is optional) is skipped all together.

I've only seen this used once in my career.

Answer (score 2):

It's considered good practice to seperate statements like BoltBait said. The reasoning is that you can't enter break points in between 2 different statements if they are on the same line seperated by a colon.

Less lines of code does not equal faster, or better code ^^