# What does colon mean in fortran?

Tags: matlab, fortran

I'm trying to convert fortran code to matlab, I was wondering if someone could help me with this subroutine.
I'm specifically asking what does the colon mean in these lines?

```
SUB Taper (a(), co(), Re(), Im())

FOR nd = 0 TO 31

         n1 = 8 * nd: n2 = a(n1 + 4): n1 = a(n1): n0 = 255 - nd
         a = .5 * (1 - co(n1)): b = .5 * (1 - co(n2))
         Re(nd) = a * Re(nd): Im(nd) = b * Im(nd)
         Re(n0) = b * Re(n0): Im(n0) = a * Im(n0)

NEXT

END SUB
```

Comment: That looks more like VB than Fortran.

Answer (score 2):

The code fragment in your question has not a valid Fortran syntax. It is VB and colon is used as [statement separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411711/using-colons-to-put-two-statements-on-the-same-line-in-visual-basic)

Answer (score -1):

Fortran90 and up allow you to access a single array value given an index, and access a subarray given a range of indices separated by a colon.

```
Fortran = Beginning : End : Increment
MatLab  = Beginning : Increment : End
```

There is a table at the bottom of page 5 in this [doc](https://www.clear.rice.edu/mech517/F90_docs/tables.pdf) that shows the Fortran and MatLab equivalents.

Comment: That is true, and there is also the colon edit descriptor in Fortran.  However, neither of these applies as the code fragment is not Fortran.

Comment: @francescalus - Agreed.

Comment: So yea it is actually basic, I thought the whole time it was fortran! That clears up a lot : P